# My very simple PHP form not doing anything

Tags: php, html

I am trying make a very simple contact form.

After filling out the information of the form, and I hit send, nothing happens. :/

I am new to this and would do a front flip once I get this to work.

I added the form in the HTML and the PHP above the code.

I have no more details to share.

```html
<?php

if($_POST["submit"]) {
    $recipient="name@email.com";
    $subject="Potential Prospect";
    $fname=$_POST["fname"];
    $lname=$_POST["lname"];
    $email=$_POST["email"];
    $message=$_POST["message"];
    $mailBody="Name: $fname/nEmail: $email/nMessage: $message";


    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $fname <$email>");

    $thankYou="<p>Thank you! Your message has been sent.</p>";
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Contact form to email</title>
</head>

<body>

<?=$thankYou ?>
<div id="contactContainer">
<form method="post" action="request.php">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
<label for="firstName">First Name*</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="fname" >
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lname" >
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="emailAddress">Email Address*</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="emailAddress" name="email" >
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="subject">Subject*</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" >
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="message">Message*</label>
<textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="3" name="message"></textarea>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitB" name="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: where is your `request.php` ? or is it your `request.php` ?

Comment: It is request.php. Click to it self

Comment: `<?=$thankYou ?>` missing the `;`, Just saying.  And  an undefined index `submit` and undefined variable `thankYou`

Comment: Other then that there is many reason an email won't send, I would start by  removing the mail part ( comment it ) and just echo something out where it is  like this  `//mail((...);` and on the next like `echo "Jello"; exit;` if you get the echo statement then you know your from is submitting correctly and the issue lies in the mail section.  As others mentioned below I would advise against using `mail` and instead use something like `PHPmailer` its very easy to use and allows you a much better API to access the mail functionality.

Comment: Do you have mail setup on your hosting i.e., localhost or any live server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitB" name="submit">Submit</button>
```

to

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitB" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

And use `if(isset($_POST["submit"]))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

first try this for handle the error .

You need to declare  `$thankYou` in top of your script so you wont see errors then add `isset()` to your `$_POST["submit"]`

Here is the working example

```
<?php
$thankYou = ""; // declare it here so you wont see any error for this variable

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) { // Adding isset here
    $recipient="name@email.com";
    $subject="Potential Prospect";
    $fname=$_POST["fname"];
    $lname=$_POST["lname"];
    $email=$_POST["email"];
    $message=$_POST["message"];
    $mailBody="Name: $fname/nEmail: $email/nMessage: $message";


  //  mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $fname <$email>");

    $thankYou="<p>Thank you! Your message has been sent.</p>";
}

?>
```

Comment: if(!$isset($_POST["submit"])) {

Comment: Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home2/travis777/rawmoneycrew.com/tinderphotography/test.php on line 3

Comment: You should remove the `$` when using `isset()`. `isset()` is a function and by prefixing it with `$` you're telling the interpreter that `isset()` is a variable.

Answer (score 0):

There are two small issues I can see that could be causing your problems, and one larger one.

First, if you're posting a form to itself, I'd advise removing the action unless the form and the request exist in different places. By removing the action the form will post to itself.

```
<form method="post">
```

Second, `$thankyou` is undefined outside of your if statement. Before the if statement you should set `$thankyou=""`. This will make sure PHP doesn't output an error for an unset variable.

Last, You're sending an email with the built in mailer. If you haven't put this on a server with a domain name set then it's likely that your emails will not be delivered. I'm not sure if it would cause an error and display nothing, but I'd comment it out until you get the form posting properly and showing the `$thankyou` output.

Try those things and if it still doesn't work, comment back and we can figure out whats wrong.

Edit: Another thing, rather than doing `if ($_POST['submit']) {`, change it to `if ($_POST) {`

Currently you're checking if the `$_POST` array exists and if the key `submit`  has a value set to a truthy value. If you just check on if the `$_POST` array exists then you'll be checking to see if an array was created rather than a key. This is a better alternative since you're not setting an input with name submit to have a value.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your button a value, like:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitB" value="sub" name="submit">Submit</button>
```

Then check for that value in the PHP, like:

```
if($_POST["submit"] == "sub")
```